# She has written novels vs. a novel

Tags: tense, perfect-constructions

When someone says "She has written a novel", the salient interpretation is that the writing is complete: the whole situation is interpreted perfectively.
However, I think it is also possible to understand it as a progressive perfect, meaning she is still writing the novel.

What is the salient interpretation of "She has written novels". Does it mean she has written a few novels, but she still have more to complete?

Comment: It is not progressive perfect, it is present perfect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not progressive. That would be "She is writing a novel". The meaning of "She has written a novel" is that the event is in the past (but making a connection to the present — the nature of that connection would be in the context)

So, "She has written a novel" means that the novel is complete, and she has finished writing it.  It is possible that she is now writing *another* novel. The grammar doesn't imply that she has stopped writing completely.

And likewise "She has written novels" means that she has completed 2 or more novels.  It implies nothing about what she is doing now. She could be writing a novel, she could be writing a play, she could be composing a symphony! Nothing is implied without context.

One important piece of context is the presence of a "since" phrase.  "I have written novels" simply means that at some points in the past I wrote 2 or more novels"  But "I've written novels since 2004" means that my writing of novels *continues to the present*.  The speaker still considers herself a "novel writer" in the present.